# RabbitMQ Management Console - node name

Tags: rabbitmq, servicebus

Can I change the node name from RabbitMq Management Console for a specific queue? I tried, but I think that this is created when I started my app. Can I change it afterwards? My queue is on node RabbitMQ1, and my connection on node RabbitMQ2, so I cannot read messages from that queue. Maybe I can change my connection node?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node name is not just a label, but it's where the queue is physically located. In fact by default queues are not distributed/mirrored, but created on the server where the application connected, as you correctly guessed.

However you can make your queue mirrored using policies, so you can consume messages from both the servers.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html

You can change the policy for the queues by using the `rabbitmqctl` command or from the management console, admin -> policies.

You need to synchronize the queue in order to clone the old messages to the mirror queue with:

```
rabbitmqctl sync_queue <queue_name>
```

Newly published messages will end in both the copies of the queue, and can be consumed from both alternatively (the same message won't be consumed from both).